# this и непонятное мне поведение

Tags: javascript, html, css

Наверное странно видеть данный вопрос от человека с такой репутацией, но я не совсем могу понять, почему данный код выдает ошибку `this.classList is undefined`

Вот пример :

```js
let acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
let i;
for(i = 0; i < acc.length; i++){
    acc[i].onclick = () => {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
    }
}
```

```css
button.accordion{
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: .4s;
}
button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
div.panel{
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
div.panel1.show{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, dignissimos.
    </p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, dignissimos.
    </p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, dignissimos.
    </p>
</div>
```

Будьте добры, обьясните, почему так, ведь `console.log[0]` например отдает нужный мне элемент.

Comment: `this` в стрелочной функции - тот же, что и в том месте, где она определена

Comment: @Igor это не работает, даже если я заменю стрелочную функцию на обыкновенную анонимную

Comment: Почему же? Ошибки не будет, `this` тогда будет кликнутым элементом. Смотрите ниже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` в стрелочной функции - тот же, что и в том месте, где она определена -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

```js
let acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
let i;
for(i = 0; i < acc.length; i++){
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
    };
}
```

```css
button.accordion{
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: .4s;
}
button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
div.panel{
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
div.panel.show{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, dignissimos.
    </p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, dignissimos.
    </p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, dignissimos.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: простите, вы как всегда правы, глупый вопрос, с очень глупой ошибкой, но спасибо за объяснения со стрелочной функцией!

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Пожалуйста. Подправил в ответе название класса `panel`  в стилях.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я сразу потом проверил)